# I've hunted a wild boar before

Tags: present-perfect, adverbs

> I've hunted a wild boar before.

The word "before" implies 1) I'm currently hunting a wild boar or 2) I'm planning to hunt one soon.

But can it imply something else? Let me give you two examples:

3)

> I'm drawing a picture of a wild boar (in the middle of drawing I say to my friend "I've hunted a wild boar before")

or

4)

> I'm hunting a moose (in the process of hunting, I say to my friend "I've hunted a wild boar before".)

Comment: "I've hunted a wild boar before" means at some point in your life,  before the present moment,  you have hunted a wild boar. It doesn't mean you are "currently hunting a wild boar or planning to hunt one soon".

Comment: I don't find your second example natural (when hunting is not being discussed). I think the artist would say "I hunted a wild boar once."

Comment: @KateBunting Is it worth mentioning that when discussing hunting animals, it is common to drop the article, and use the singular, e.g. 'I've never hunted wild boar before', 'this gun is loaded for bear'? Of course we may also discuss hunting a particular animal.

Comment: @None It doesn't mean you are "currently hunting a wild boar or planning to hunt one soon", but the word "before" implies it, I think. If you mean at some point in your life, before the present moment, you have hunted a wild boar, you would just say "I've hunted a wild boar". You wouldn't add "before". If you add "before", the natural question is "before what?" "I've seen a wild boar before" implies you're looking at one at the moment, for example.

Comment: It seems you are confused about the meaning of "before". It just means any time before  the present moment (or the moment you are talking about).

Comment: @None - Yes, it does, but when we speak of having 'done something before', we usually mean 'before the present occasion of doing it'.

Comment: @None Sorry, but do you mean "I've done something before" and "I've done something" are totally the same? Do these mean the same? "I've been to Germany" vs "I've been to Germany before". "I've eaten sushi" vs "I've eaten sushi before". "I've watched this movie" vs "I've watched this movie before".

Comment: I'm not saying they mean exactly the same. It's just most of the time we would  not have  "I've done this"  on its own, it's as if the sentence isn't finished. It can be "before" or some other words. If you want to say you hunted wild boar once (or more times) in your life you can say "I've already hunted (a) wild boar", and it doesn't mean you're hunting one now. You can be sitting at home when saying it.

Comment: @Stephen - You: Are you comfortable hunting wild cougars?  Me: I've hunted wild boar before.  We are sitting on the couch watching TV while we have this conversation.  Your belief of how *before* is used is incorrect but your question acknowledging the different usages is correct.  What kind of answer are you looking for?

Comment: English speakers often use before incorrectly. Kate is right here. The word before implies you are doing the thing in the present. Otherwise, there is no need to say before.

Comment: @Lambie - I can't find that definition.  Before just means during an earlier time or proceeding a particular event.  Is your comment correct?

Comment: @EllieK I have seen this reaction before., :)

Comment: @Lambie - You are correct.  :)  I thought the same as I was writing it.  I think the point I'm making is that it doesn't matter if you *need* to say it.  I upvoted Kates's comment because it's true but that wasn't the OP's question.  They asked what it means if it is said.

Comment: Kate said "when we speak of having 'done something before', we usually mean 'before the present occasion of doing it'". In my OP, I said *I've hunted a wild boar before* implies "I'm hunting a wild boar". We agree. But others say it can imply anything.

Comment: If it can imply anything, I think the four scenarios in my OP are all possible, aren't they?

Answer (score 1):

As *None* points out in his comment, *before* merely means *before this moment (the moment I'm speaking)*.  The meaning that *you* as a listener/reader infer from this statement has a lot to do with context.

If I'm drawing a picture of a wild boar and I say to you, *I've hunted a wild boar before*, all that statement means is that at some time before today I hunted a wild boar.  What you take away from that meaning has everything to do with the context of our conversation, our history together, and our relationship.

The reason for my saying that could be as simple as *I would like to talk about wild boars with you.*

As Kate and Lambie point out in their comments *before* is commonly used to indicate that we are actively doing something that we've done before.  If we were hunting wild boar and you asked me, *Does this scare you?* I would respond, *No, I've hunted wild boar **before***. In that situation the *before* is helpful and not redundant.  It is used to differentiate this hunt from a previous hunt when we use a present perfect tense.  Merely responding, *I've hunted wild boar,* in that situation could (does?) include this hunt.

In your example the *before* is not needed.  It's implied that the time you hunted wild boar was before now.  If we are not currently hunting, when else could it be?  People do, however, include the redundant before and the meaning remains the same, *I've hunted wild boar before [now].*

Your four scenarios are all possible but you will most commonly hear the third one without *before* added at the end.

Comment: Kate said "when we speak of having 'done something before', we usually mean 'before the present occasion of doing it'". In my OP, I said I've hunted a wild boar before implies "I'm hunting a wild boar". We agree. But others say it can imply anything. If it can imply anything, I think the four scenarios in my OP are all possible, aren't they?

Answer (score 0):

- In general using the Present Perfect supposes that an action was pulled off at an indefinite moment in the past time  span coming up to the present. It's a kind of   the Indefinite article. I.e. when you bring up an issue for the first time you use the Pr.Perfect and then you switch to the Past Indefinite:

"I've hunted a boar before. I hunted it in the grove. He pounced on me and I hardly made it away".

- The Pr. Perfect can also allude to recurrent actions in the past: "I've hunted the wild boar before quite a few times".

or "Every time I have hunted wild boar it has been pouncing on me".